# remote debug a Docker Container runnig on linux from windows using intellij IDEA

Tags: linux, windows, docker, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

Can someone explain to me how I can debug my container running on a Linux server from my Windows environment using intellij IDEA?
is that even possible?
I have packed a Spring boot application in a container and now want to debug this container.

Comment: Hello! You can set up the [remote Docker](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-docker.html#b2c21a4b) configuration and follow [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-a-java-app-in-a-container.html) on how to debug the application in the Docker container.

Answer (score 1):

First: it is actually possible to debug a Docker container running on a Linux environment from the local Windows environment.
Secondly: you need to make some changes to the docker-compose.yaml. For example, I simply specified expose. In order to integrate the container port with the Linux port, you also have to define a port field in the  docker-compose.yaml file.
So the steps are now as follows:

1. Enable remote debug in intellij under edit configurations.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVqtB.png)
2. create an ssh connection to linux.
3. Integrate container port with linux port.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A082a.png)
4. configure your dockerfile and add cmd command
   CMD [ "java","-jar","-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005", "yourapp-boot.jar"]
5. Start container through intellij IDEA with debug mode.